# Codeigniter sessions - a lot of rows by bots

Tags: session, codeigniter-2, bots

everyone.
I have a problem with **CI sessions**.
There is part of my config for sessions:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```

Over a short period of time, a large amount (about 200 000) of sessions are created by bots/spiders. Like :

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
```

Is there a way of preventing this? 
I read the answer for [12241701](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241701) question. but I do not know what I should write in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as you're keeping your sessions forever `$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;` you're going to run in to this "problem".

If you want to use the .htaccess file from the article you linked to yourself, then use it exactly as it appears in that answer.

What it's doing is slowing the crawl rate of all spiders, except Baidu and Soso (they are both Chinese search engines) which it's outright banning from crawling.

I presume you don't want to actually ban nice search engines from crawling your site, so that is probably your best option.